# Using Apache Directory API in Spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ldap

I am trying to use the `org.apache.directory.api` to create a connection to an LDAP service and query it as part of an Spark application. The Scala code for connecting and querying the LDAP works as intended when I use it as part of an Java application, but when executed as part of a Spark application it produces an error message like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.directory.api.util.Strings.toLowerCaseAscii(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.api.DefaultConfigurableBinaryAttributeDetector.addBinaryAttribute(DefaultConfigurableBinaryAttributeDetector.java:166)
        at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.api.DefaultConfigurableBinaryAttributeDetector.setBinaryAttributes(DefaultConfigurableBinaryAttributeDetector.java:206)
        at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.api.DefaultConfigurableBinaryAttributeDetector.<init>(DefaultConfigurableBinaryAttributeDetector.java:133)
        at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.buildConfig(LdapNetworkConnection.java:599)
        at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.<init>(LdapNetworkConnection.java:410)
```

The exception is raised the very first time i try to create the network connection:

```
val ldapConnection = new LdapNetworkConnection(endpoint, port, true)
```

In the dependency tree I can see that the `api-util` also is part of an Spark dependency, but in the tree it is marked to be omitted due to conflict with my version - however as this jar is provided I am not sure if it is loaded first and therefor my dependency is ignored:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:jar:2.3.0.cloudera2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.13.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.13.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.13.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- (org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:provided - omitted for conflict with 1.0.3)
```

I can't see why this call would end up in a method that don't exists, or what the error might be. Any suggestion how to solve or debug this?

Comment: What version of ldap api are you using? Also, is it a single `api-all-xxx.jar`, or you have a separate `api-util-xxx.jar`?

Comment: I am using the 1.0.3 version, and i am using maven to create an uber jar including all dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, it was due to the Spark dependency to an LDAP package that is a different version. I solved it by shading the needed Apache packages, like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>${jarNameWithDependencies}</shadedClassifierName>
        <artifactSet>
            <includes>
                <include>*:*</include>
            </includes>
        </artifactSet>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.apache.directory</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.apache.shaded.directory</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.apache.mina</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.apache.shaded.mina</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```